# 'Have a shortage of' vs 'be short of'

Tags: phrase-choice

Edited:
Which one of the following self-made sentences sounds more idiomatic to you:

> - We will **have a shortage of** rice in the next year.
> - We will **be short of** rice in the next year.

They both mean the same to me, but I need to know they both work the same with e.g. the noun "rice".

Comment: **have a shortage** suggests some widespread issue, for example at national level. **be short of** suggests something more personal, for example the rice container in the kitchen is almost empty. For this reason, only the latter is used in the many idiomatic ways of suggesting that somebody is not very bright, for example "he's a few sandwitches short of a picnic".

Comment: Neither are idiomatically natural (either delete the article in ***the** next year*, or precede it with ***over / during*** or similar). Other than that it's largely just a stylistic choice, except that ***a shortage*** might more strongly imply a more extensive deficit (it's more likely a *nation* might suffer a shortage/shortfall, where with a *family* they might just ***go / be short***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers please have a look on the page bellow: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+next+year%2Cover+the+next+year%2Cduring+the+next+year&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20next%20year%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cover%20the%20next%20year%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20the%20next%20year%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The search terms in that NGram aren't sufficient to limit us to the context under consideration (specifically, a *continuous, ongoing state* which will come to pass in the coming year). Note that the *in general* we don't use ***in the*** in your context (see [this ELU question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103371/)) except where what's going to happen is a single time-specific event, such as *The chairmain announced that he well retire [some time] in the next year* (but even there ***in the*** is only optional, not required).